# How to edit multiple tables in MVC using ViewModel pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**I am trying to perform CURD operation in MVC web application in a webgrid but the problem is I have multiple tables but don't know how to perform EDIT operation by using multiple tables.**

Invoice table

```
public Invoice()
{
    this.LineItems = new HashSet<LineItem>();
}

public int Customer_ID { get; set; }
public string Customer_name { get; set; }
public string Customer_Address { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
```

Product Table

```
public Produc()
{
    this.LineItems = new HashSet<LineItem>();
}

public int Product_ID { get; set; }
public string Product_name { get; set; }
public int Unit_Price { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
```

LineItems Table

```
public partial class LineItem
{
    public int Customer_ID { get; set; }
    public int LineItems_ID { get; set; }
    public int Product_ID { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }

    public virtual Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
    public virtual Produc Produc { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string Customer_name { get; set; }
    public string Customer_Address { get; set; }        
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public string Product_name { get; set; }
    public int Unit_Price { get; set; }
}
```

here is a class which will perform CURD operation for me

```
public class Class1
{
    SalesOrderEntities entities = new SalesOrderEntities();

    public bool SaveStudent(ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        try
        {
            var Invoice = new Invoice()
            {
                Customer_name = viewModel.Customer_name,
                Customer_Address = viewModel.Customer_Address
            };
            var LineItem = new LineItem()
            {
                Quantity = viewModel.Quantity,
                Total = viewModel.Total
            };
            var Produc = new Produc()
            {
                Product_name=viewModel.Product_name,
                Unit_Price=viewModel.Unit_Price
            };
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {

            return false;
        }

    }

    public bool UpdateStudent()
    {
        try
        {

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }
```

Now, here i have problem i don't know how to perform edit functionality.

Comment: Have you implemented DBContext?

Comment: yes i did but only in tables invoice, Products & LineItems but not in viewModel

Comment: Ok. You have long and description answer for your question. Is that work for you?

Comment: no actually not the second part that updating part actually its like a point of sale software what i actually want i want to retrieve fields from all my 3 tables not only from one table.like i want customer name,Customer_Address From Invoice table & Quantity From LineItems tables &Product_name,Unit_Price from Product table and how to do that. Because i am confused when i click on edit button only a specific table id will be use whether i want fields from different tables

Comment: You need to join the table to get data.
You want to get Customer Detail from CustomerID?

Comment: exactly this is i want but can u write this function for me

Comment: Tell me the declaration of that function, Like that function return ViewModel object. Something like that: `public ViewModel GetData(int studentID)
    { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

Updating using Entity Framework can be fairly straight-forward as it supports change-tracking by default. Change tracking will let EF automatically manage any changes that occur to your entities once they are pulled, so that when you call `SaveChanges()`, these same changes will be made at the database-level.

**Example Adding New Entities**

Since you already have your data context, when you are creating your new entities, you'll just need to ensure that you add them to the context properly and save the changes after that is done :

```
// Add each of your new entities to their appropriate table in the context and then save
// your changes
entities.Invoices.Add(new Invoice(){
    Customer_name = viewModel.Customer_name,
    Customer_Address = viewModel.Customer_Address
});
entities.LineItems.Add(new LineItem(){
    Quantity = viewModel.Quantity,
    Total = viewModel.Total
});
entities.Producs.Add(new Produc(){
    Product_name = viewModel.Product_name,
    Unit_Price = viewModel.Unit_Price
});
// Now save your changes
entities.SaveChanges();
```

**Example Updating Existing Entities**

Updating will essentially work the same way, however you will want to have access to the identifier so that you can query the existing entity, make your changes and save them :

```
public ActionResult UpdateStudent(int studentId)
{
     using(var entities = new SalesOrderEntities())
     {
          // Get your student
          var student = entities.Students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StudentID == studentId);
          if(student == null)
          {
               // Student wasn't found
               return HttpNotFound();
          }
          // Create a view with the existing student data
          return View(student);
     }

}

[HttpPost]
public bool UpdateStudent(UpdateStudentViewModel viewModel)
{
     try
     {
         using(var entities = new SalesOrderEntities())
         {
              // Retrieve your existing student (or other entities)
              var existingStudent = entities.Students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StudentID == viewModel.StudentID);
              // Now that you have your entity, update the appropriate properties
              existingStudent.Property = viewModel.Property;
              // Then finally save your changes
              entities.SaveChanges();
         }
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
         // Something went wrong updating the user
     }
}
```

Comment: viewModel,StudentID doesnt work coz view models do no have any id viewModel class is just a pattern to work with multiple tables this class takes value and throw the value in corresponding tables but how to edit multiple tables at the same time with same id.

Comment: This was just an example of how it might work. You would read whatever your ID value was from your view model and query using it from your individual tables to retrieve the appropriate entities to change. You would then make your changes to the entities and call SaveChanges() to save them to the database.

Comment: my question is just simple that how to play with multiple table edit and delete not how to save. The problem is Right here                                   var existingStudent = entities.Students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StudentID == viewModel.StudentID);
i think there is should be use of join but i dnt knw how to join.
if u have any other code snippet or article kindly refer me.